# how to get Value from ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have two classes, `A` and `B`. `A extends Dialog` and `B extends ArrayAdapter`. I obtain double value in `B`. I want to get it in `A`. Is there any possible way for this?

Answer (score -1):

Does this answer your question?

```
double value = (double) adapterB.getItem(position);
dialogA.setMessage("Value from adapter: "+value);
```